# Duplicate Ids on jquerymobile ajax page

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

When navigation around pages with ajax (jquerymobile), I see that the DOM (page) is duplicate

[image: Duplicate page]

The old page (/question/index/11?type=all) and the new page(/question/index/4?type=all) have the same structure and same IDs, so all Ids in div(data-role=page) are duplicated -> my events are going wrong.
Is there any option for ajax loading page in jquerymobile can remove all DOM in old page?

Comment: Remove page once you leave it on `pagehide`.

Comment: Can you add the sample code because ajax page load is automatically done by jquerymobile framework :-(

Comment: It depends on your pages structure. Pls post your code and how you load pages.

Comment: I don't load the page by myself, I just put the link and jquerymobile load it using ajax, then you can see in attached image, when it load a new page, it doesn't remove the old page in DOM, it add a new page with data-role=page. Because there pages (question pages) have the same ids then it makes my js code is going wrong :-<